# Python via matplotlib and cartopy draws some points and ignores others, why?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geo, cartopy

In Python 3.8.5 using matplotlib 3.3.2 and cartopy 0.18.0, I plot a DataFrame of points on the globe using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.io.img_tiles
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def plotPt(xx,clr=['red'],msize=[1.0],name=''):  #plots the geo points on a globe
    terrain=cartopy.io.img_tiles.Stamen('terrain-background') #Create a Stamen terrain background instance.
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    a=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=cartopy.crs.EqualEarth()) #Create a GeoAxes in the tile's projection. 
    #projection: terrain.crs or cartopy.crs. with Orthographic(),Mollweide(),Robinson(),EqualEarth(),PlateCarree()
    x=pd.concat(xx); rng= [x['LON'].min(),x['LON'].max(),x['LAT'].min(),x['LAT'].max()]; del x #range of the map
    a.set_extent(rng,crs=cartopy.crs.Geodetic()) #Limit the extent of the map to a small longitude/latitude range.
    a.add_image(terrain,5) #Add the Stamen data at specified zoom level. 
    for i in range(len(xx)):
        a.plot(xx[i]['LON'],xx[i]['LAT'], color=clr[i], linewidth=0, marker='o', markersize=msize[i], alpha=0.99, transform=cartopy.crs.Geodetic())
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1,wspace=0,hspace=0);   plt.show()
    #fig.savefig('/home/leon/plotPt'+name+'.png',bbox_inches='tight')

n=100; x=pd.DataFrame([(lat,lon) for lat in np.linspace(20,30,n) for lon in np.linspace(-100,-80,n)],columns=['LAT','LON']); plotPt([x],['red'],[1]) 
y=pd.read_csv('/home/leon/points.csv')[['LAT','LON']]; print(y); plotPt([y],['red'],[10])
```

The second DataFrame `y` can be downloaded here: https://gofile.io/d/oyCL1r The two obtained pictures are [image] [image]
As you can see, the first pic is correct, but the second plots only one point, even though the contents of my file points.csv are:

```
            LAT       LON
0     24.989950 -97.47495
1     24.989950 -97.43487
2     25.055276 -97.43487
3     24.989950 -97.39479
4     25.055276 -97.39479
...         ...       ...
6657  26.361809 -80.04008
6658  23.095477 -80.00000
6659  23.422111 -80.00000
6660  23.487437 -80.00000
6661  25.839196 -80.00000

[6662 rows x 2 columns]
```

How can I make sure all points are plotted? Also, the map is zoomable, is there a way to save it and preserve this feature?

Comment: Can you post your csv file somewhere and link to it? You could probably post it on https://pastebin.com

Comment: @DopplerShift Thank you for your response. I have uploaded the file and gave a link to it in the opening post. Do you have some clue about why the problem occurs?

Answer (score 1):

For the second plot, I write a short script and run it and get the points plotted.

```
from io import StringIO

# data for check plot
str = """ID  LAT  LON
0  24.989950 -97.47495
1  24.989950 -97.43487
2  25.055276 -97.43487
3  24.989950 -97.39479
4  25.055276 -97.39479
7  26.361809 -80.04008
8  23.095477 -80.00000
9  23.422111 -80.00000
10  23.487437 -80.00000
11  25.839196 -80.00000"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str), sep='\s+', index_col='ID')
#df  #OK

# plot the data
plotPt([df],['red'],[1])
```

[image: so_plot]

For zooming and interactive abilities on your maps look for `folium`.

Comment: If I plot only a subset of `x`, I get all the points, but when plotting the whole `x`, only one point is in the picture. Where can I upload my CSV file, so you can see the problem yourself?

Comment: @Leo Check your data, try basic min max ave.

Comment: I don't undrstand what you mean by min/avg/max. As stated, the problem occurs occasionally, not always. An example is my file, which I'm eager to share, just don't know how.

Comment: @Leo In your case, simple plots of data, `x['LON'].plot()` and `x['LAT'].plot()` can give some idea about the data. But the broblem can be other reasons.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the data. I can plot it normally with another method (using `plotly`, but the pic isn't as fancy looking). That's why I'd like to make this method work correctly.